# How do i format the equations so that they show up aligned?

Tags: equations, align

I have

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(n) = \phi(pq) = & pq - (\# of multiples of p) - (\# of multiples of q) + (\# of multiples of pq) \\
& = & pq - q - p +1 \\
& = & (p-1)(1-1) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

But the last two equations on the RHS are to the far right and not aligned under the first RHS equation.

Also I get "# of multiples of p" all bunched up together .. how do i fix that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For your second problem: If you want to write text in math mode, wrap it into a `\text` command, i.e. `\text{$\#$ of multiples of $p$}`.

Comment: Please read [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln).

Comment: @moewe - Unless the text-mode and math-mode symbols for `#` are different, it's not necessary to surround the `\#` particles with `$` symbols, right?

Comment: @Mico Exactly, but I wasn't sure about a difference in the output and would have preferred to see the math-mode `#` in this context (if there is a difference).

Answer (score 3):

I would use an `align*` environment instead of an `eqnarray*` environment; the latter is [badly deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). In the `align` environment, a single `&` symbol is used to mark the alignment point.

To typeset strings of "normal text" in upright-roman rather than math-italic, use the `\text` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\phi(n) = \phi(pq) &= pq - (\text{\# of multiples of $p$}) - 
     (\text{\# of multiples of $q$}) + (\text{\# of multiples of $pq$}) \\
&= pq - q - p +1 \\
&= (p-1)(1-1) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have one `&` in the first line, but two in the other lines. With `eqnarray` you need an `&` on either side of the `=` for things to align correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(n) = \phi(pq) & = & pq - \text{(\# of multiples of \(p\)) - (\# of multiples of \(q\)) + (\# of multiples of \(pq\))} \\
 & = & pq - q - p +1 \\
 & = & (p-1)(1-1) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `align` is much preferred to `eqnarray`. See [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/24974) for reasons why.

Comment: eqnarray should always have two `&` the right hand side above is centred as that is supposed to be the middle column with the _operator_   eqnarray is intended to set the right hand slide left aligned.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah yes, I guess I should have read the link more closely myself. I have updated my answer. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Comment: +1 for providing an excellent example of why one should *not* use `eqnarray` (and, instead, should use `align`): The first row contains two `=` symbols, and the amount of whitespace placed around them is wildly different, courtesy of `eqnarray`'s shortcomings...